# Using VBA to open Embedded PowerPoint Template in Excel File

Tags: excel, vba, object, office365, powerpoint

I have an excel file where people model data, and then they have to copy and paste a bunch of excel ranges to a powerpoint file for review.  I am creating VBA to automatically open a powerpoint file that is embedded in the excel template, update the links, and save as a new file.

Everything works fine when I run it on my PC, but when I send it to someone else, I believe it is still trying to look for the embedded file through a file path, instead of finding it as a stored file within excel.  Am I missing something with how I embedded the file?

Used Insert Object -> Create From File -> Browse to correct file -> Display as Icon

Here is the code that works correctly on my machine, but doesn't work when I send it to someone else:

```
Sub CreateDealReviewPPT()

    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Dim pptPresentation As Object


Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")

SaveDir = Sheets("Start Here - ISSP Instructions").Range("SaveDir").Value
CustomerName = Sheets("Start Here - ISSP Instructions").Range("CustomerName").Value
Version = Sheets("Start Here - ISSP Instructions").Range("Version").Value

'Open the PowerPoint template that is embedded into the document
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Object 1").Select

    Selection.Verb Verb:=xlOpen

    PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Object 2").LinkFormat.Update
    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Object 4").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(6).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes("Object 5").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(9).Shapes("Object 2").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(10).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(11).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(12).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(13).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    'Need to check on this one as its a picture not a range
    'PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(14).Shapes("Object 5").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(15).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(16).Shapes("Object 1").LinkFormat.Update

    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs Filename:=SaveDir & CustomerName & "v" & Version & ".ppt"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    PowerPointApp.Quit

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Call BreakLinks

End Sub
```

I've seen this done with a Word document successfully, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to get it to work for ppt.  It works fine as is, but if I send to someone else, or if I rename the Excel file and put it in a new location on my computer, it still looks to the file path where it existed when the file was embedded.

Comment: The LinkFormat.Update method is specific to _linked_ OLE objects: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-delete-bookmarks-in-a-word-document-or-outlook-message-f68d781f-0150-4583-a90e-a4009d99c2a0 What are the symptoms at the recipient's end? Do they see an error message? If so, what is the message and what line triggers it?

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thanks.  I am trying to take screen shots now. When I run the macro, it opens the ppt file, and asks if I want to update links.  If I click update, it has a message that says "sorry we couldn't find all linked files...."  Then it errors on the line in the code where it tries to select the first shape.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I couldn't get the images to load, but i'll try again in a moment.  I think its finding the embedded file and opening it correctly, but the links that exist in that powerpoint are looking for a location that doesn't exist.  Is there a way to have the embedded file link accurately?   Or do I need to create code to update the link to the active excel document?

Comment: Links in the embedded PowerPoint will be pointing at an external file. Is that an Excel file? Is it the file that contains the embedded PowerPoint? OLE Links to files include the complete path name. That path name will always be different on a different computer.

Comment: Yes.  The excel file is the file that contains the embedded PPT.  Can I go through and update all links in the embedded ppt to link to the excel file?  Probably utilizing ActiveWorkbook.FullName to update the path name?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.